# Class Architecture: Circular Dependency of Inner and Outer Class in Python

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, monkeypatching, decoupling

## My Design

### Verbal Description

I have a class `Model`, of course with some methods on it. Besides that I have a class `ModelList` whose childclass represents a List of instances of q child class of `Model`. Amongst other things, the use of `ModelList` child classes is to provide bulk operations which differ from just delegating the operation to each of the elements of the `ModelList`. So, the purpose of the `ModelList` child classes is to  "vectorize" methods of the corresponding `Model` class.

I also use the `ModelList` in some places where I want to allow either a childclass of `Model` or `ModelList` allowed as parameter passed to a function.

`ModelList` is knowing (and checking) the type that will be accepted for any of its elements. To make the `ModelList` childclass know its corresponding `Model` child class, I define this as a class variable `element_type` on the `ModelList` child class.

Each `ModelList` child class is closely coupled to a `Model` childclass: One `ModelList` class belongs to one `Model` class. That's why I put the `ModelList` child class as an inner classes to their respective `Model` class. An here comes my problem: Because `ModelList` needs to know `Model` and `Model` needs to know `ModelList` and both during initialisation of each class, I have a circular dependency between my classes.

### Minimum Example

I reduced my code to a Minimum Example to make my design easier understandable:

```py
class Model(ABC):
    pass
```

```py
class ModelList(list):
    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, elements=None):
        elements = list() if not elements else elements

        for value in elements:
            self._check_type(value)

        list.__init__(self, elements)

    def _check_type(self, val):
        if not isinstance(val, self.__class__.element_type):
            raise TypeError(
            f"{self.__class__} accepts only instances of {self.__class__.element_type} as elements. `{val}` is not!")
```

The following leads to the Error `free variable 'SomeModel' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope`:

```py
class SomeModel(Model):
    class List(ModelList):
        element_type = SomeModel  # this causes the Error
```

## I do not want to decouple

I know I can get rid of the circular dependency by just decoupling the two classes. But I do *want* both the `Model` class know its corresponding `ModelList` class and also I want the `ModelList` class to know its `Model` class. Each `Model` class ought to have one and only one `List` attached to it.

## Is monkey patching appropriate?

I know I can circumvent the dependency by "monkeypatching" my `Model` child class like this:

```py
class SomeModel(Model):
    pass

class SomeModelList(ModelList):
        element_type = SomeModel

SomeModel.List = SomeModelList
```

For me it feels like this is a sign of a design flaw. I cannot say why but it feels "wrong".

## Questions

1. Is monkeypatching appropriate here? Or is it indicating a deeper conceptual problem of my design?
2. Which other solutions are there?
3. How can I redesign to get rid of this circular dependency (but still keep the coupling of the classes)?
4. Is it possible to evaluate the `element_type` at some point later when the respective `Model` childclass is defined?

Comment: It seems like you want to create a typesafe list, but note that you can still add objects of another type to your list class by usind append, insert, + or +=.

Comment: @sloth Thanks, I am aware of this and I have added all the magic methods to assure that those list operations will generate an instance of the `ModelList`
 childclass. I just did not mention them here for the sake of creating a minimal example. I think, I should have left out the inheritance of `list` as well to create a true ME.

Comment: Yes, all those issues are telling you that the design is flawed, but you already knew that beforehand and you said that you want it flawed. If the reasons that make that kind of design considered flawed do not matter much to you or it buys you something that you value more than the potential problems, just go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to make SomeModelList behave like a generic, you should provide the element class as a parameter of the constructor and assign it to self.element_type there.

```
class ModelList(list):

    def __init__(self, model, elements=None):
        self.element_Type = model 
        elements = list() if not elements else elements

        for value in elements:
            self._check_type(value)

        list.__init__(self, elements)

    def _check_type(self, val):
        if not isinstance(val, self.element_type):
            raise TypeError(
            f"{self.__class__} accepts only instances of {self.element_type} as elements. `{val}` is not!") 


# usage

modelList = ModelList(SomeModel,[instance1,instance2,instance3])
```

You could then generalize this by adding a class method to your Model base class (assuming you define ModelList before Model):

```
class Model:

    ... your other methods ...

    @classmethod
    def List(self,elements=None):
        return ModelList(self.__class__,elements)

# usage

class SomeModel(Model): pass

modelList = SomeModel.List([instance1,instance2,instance3])
```

Comment: Added example of how to generalize use of ModelList in the Model class.

Comment: How could I have found that solution on my own?